# How to get the URL without the Query String or the Id part?

Tags: c#, url, httpcontext

Let's say my urls are:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company/employees/5
https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company/employees?id=5&name=jack
https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company/employees/5?clockId=1
```

I'm looking for a way to get the "base" path, or whatever it's called. Like the "base" path would be "/app/company/employees" for all, without the "/5" part or "?id=5&name=jack" or "/5?clockId=1" parts.

I was using `string.Join("/", context.Request.ApplicationPath, context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"])` to get it (context is HttpContext), but it doesn't work the way I want since it includes the Index action too. Like if the Url is "https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company" I want "/app/company/" not "/app/company/Index". I can always check if the action is Index or not but it feels like kind of a "code smell" to me.

Also using `context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesn't work either since it returns "/app/company/employees/5" (It returns the path with Id)

Comment: Index is your action, if you don't want the action then why are you appending it?

Comment: why dont you take host name + /app/company it is fixed

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ the question is how he should get `/app/company` ?

Comment: Will this work for custom routes? Or does this happen **after** the url has been mapped to a controller and action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only two things you need from URL are `action` and `controller` and if the action is "index" you don't need it. In this case I believe that you are doing it right. This is a slightly modified piece of code I was using in `ASP.NET MVC` project:

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
if (actionName.Equals("index", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    actionName = string.Empty;
}
string result = $"/{controllerName}/{actionName}";
```

There is one more thing to mention: "areas". Once I was working on website which had them, so they may appear in your URL too if your website uses "area" approach.

I hope it helps